# RFID kits for experimenting

Tags: rfid, texas-instruments

I need a RFID kit for some experiments, can anyone recommend me a good one (low or high frequency are fine), maybe from Texas Instruments? It should provide API for communicating and programming, best will be compatible with Java language.
Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try searching the TI website, cher ami?

Comment: Hi, sorry for this unspecified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SparkFun and AdaFruit are the obvious choices. But in general don't expect the comfort of a Java API. What you'll have typically is a virtual serial port (which can obviously be handled with almost any language). It's your job to encode the commands and decode the responses that'll go through this port, according to the device documentation.